# Error using excel ODBC driver in classic asp

Tags: excel, asp-classic, odbc

I am getting this error when I try to load an excel document as a datasource for my webpage

```
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80004005' 

[Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver]General error Unable to open registry key 'Temporary (volatile) Jet DSN for process 0xd5c Thread 0x7e4 DBC 0x19acf74 Excel'.
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: Most probably this is a problem with connection string. What's your connection string?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The Problem is most likly that the path the excel file is wrong the message is a red herning its nothing to do with the registry

You will have some a bit like this check the generated path is correct

```
objConn.Open "Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};DriverId=790;Dbq="&server.MapPath("\Resources\uploads\filername.XLS")&";DefaultDir="&server.MapPath("\Resources\uploads\")
```

Comment: I am marking as the answer as I am provide a reference for the bug/error

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Pbearne; the text of the message looks related to some internal aspect of the driver rather than the "real" reason for the problem.

- my first guess would be permissions
- I'd also suggest using the newer Jet OLE BE provider (http://www.carlprothman.net/Default.aspx?tabid=87#OLEDBProviderForMicrosoftJetExcel) rather than the Excel ODBC driver

Comment: Yes upgrade the the new driver is a better call

Comment: Not a bad answer, but the Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 driver has a memory leak: repeated use of the OLEDB connection opened by this driver blocks access to the clipboard and eventually crashes the application. The latest driver, Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0, has the same problem connecting to Excel: Microsoft aren't going to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

As a first step use forward slashes in MapPath i.e. /Resources/uploads/filername.XLS

Then verify path is correct.

Try the following to see if it points to the right file:

```
Response.Write server.MapPath("/Resources/uploads/filername.XLS")
```